# Make the object to be align right with vertical middle

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the text "Hellow World!" to be to the align right and to be vertical middle.

Don't know how to do it.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/5945/
```

Thanks!

It should be working for IE, CHrome and FF.

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Hello World!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `display: table-cell;`

All browsers - http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/BRxKX/5946/)**

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve vertical-centering is by making the line-height the same as the div height:

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Hello World!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a before element with a width on 0 to give it something to align to. 
HTML:

```
<div>
<p>
Hello World!
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;  

}
p {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
p:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the block only for "Hello world", then I would do the following:

```
div {
display:inline-table;
max-width:300px;
padding:50px 100px;
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;

}
```

It uses padding and display of inline-table to draw the box. You can change padding values as per your need.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox option

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World!
</div>
```